# How to trigger a click on a given event in FullCalendar v5?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar v5 instance where I want to be able to open a modal with a given event id to display its details coming from such a URL:

`https://localhost/calendar?eventId=1`

With version 3 of FullCalendar this is how I used to do it with jQuery:

```js
$("#list-event-1").trigger("click");
```

With the following  DOM element:

```html
<a id="list-event-1" class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable">
```

I don't find how to do it in v5 of FullCalendar.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) helps you

Comment: Why do you need to trigger the click of the event? If you know which event you want to click, then by definition you know which data you want to put in the modal, so why not just open the modal directly? It's unclear why triggering a specific UI action is necessary for that